# create a column that contains the iteration number belonging to each dataframe I have iterated

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, multiple-columns

I want to create a column (Stage) in each database that I have iterated. However, I want it to count the iteration number of the table. The code is as follows.

```
cnt = 10  
dict_of_df = {} 

for i in range(0,10):
    #newname = df['col'].values[i]
    dict_of_df["df_{}".format(i)] = sql_query1
    dict_of_df["df_{}".format(i)]['Stage'] = format(i)
```

However, when I get the results the `Stage` column of  `dict_of_df["df_0"]`  does not contain values equal to 0 and the `Stage` column of `dict_of_df["df_1"]`
does not contain values equal to 1.

Does anyone know how to correct this script? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, you want a column `Stage` in all DFs such that DF_i has `stage` = i. You need to remove format(i) from the RHS of the assignment, your for loop should look like this

```
for i in range(10):
   dict_if_df[f"df_{i}"]['Stage'] = i
```

Assuming `sql_query1` actually loads a df and dict_of_df is a k,v pair for the dfs. You can use f-strings in Py3.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. However, I have tried to put  ```dict_of_df["df_{}".format(i)]['Stage'] = i ``` but it still doesn't work, the ``` Stage```  column gives a value of 9 for all df_{}. If you have another comment on how to fix it, I would really appreciate it. And yes ``` sql_query1 ```  is the dataframe I want to iterate.

Comment: If you're using the same DF object for all df_i, it would replace all stage values because of a shallow copy. You can make a deep copy by `from copy import deepcopy`. And then while assigning the df_i in the dictionary, make sure you refer the key to a deepcopy of the sqldf